# SSH connection to remote docker container

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, docker

I'm trying to connect via SSH to a remote docker container from my computer for debugging purposes.

The docker container is hosted on a remote host. My docker image exposes the 25 port and inside this docker container I have set ssh on port 25. The docker image is launch with the -p 25:25 parameter.

When I'm on the remote host I can connect to the container via `ssh root@localhost -p 25` just fine. But from my computer, if I do `ssh root@host-ip -p 25` I'm getting this error: `ssh: connect to host [host-ip] port 25: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

Am I missing a port redirection or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the port 25 is also opened on the host (example on my ubuntu vm)?

```
sudo ufw status
```

If not, you can add it

```
sudo ufw allow 25/tcp
```

Comment: Yes it's already allowed:
`25/tcp  ALLOW Anywhere`

Comment: I think you will need to set port forwarding from host to container ip. First get the ip of the running container: docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" Container_Name

Then add port forwarding: iptables -t nat -D DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp --dport 25-j DNAT --to-destination Container_ip_from_previous_command:25

Comment: when I try to add the port forwarding I'm getting this error: `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): invalid port/service 25-j' specified`, what should I do? :/

Comment: my mistake, there is a missing space between 25 and -j